# Docker - x509:certificate signed by unknown authority error in windows 7

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I have installed `Docker toolbox` on `windows 7` 64 bit. When I try to run `docker run hello-world` command to verify my installation I get following error:

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get http
s://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I am behind company firewall and also I have added proxy info in Docker Toolbox\start.sh file:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="ip address:port"
export HTTPS_PROXY="ip address:port"
```

below line `export PATH="/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox:$PATH"`

I am getting same error **`**x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**`** when I run docker-compose command.

How I can resolve this error. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After removing proxy docker works fine and I am able to pull images.